# Como inserir vários valores em um array?

Tags: java, array, orientação-a-objetos

Um aluno pode pegar vários cursos como "inglês", "português" etc. Como faço para colocar vários nomes de cursos em um *array*? Não quero fazer o exemplo com `ArrayList`. É só para tirar uma dúvida minha mesmo. Então terei que criar os métodos para adicionar, remover, exibir e editar? Como fazer?

PS: `AlunoPrivado extends Aluno`.

O problema é que não estou conseguindo fazer isso. Eu fiz assim:

```
aluno.setCursos("matemática");
```

Mas está errado, como é que faço isso?

```
 public class Aluno {

   private String nome;
   private String matricula;
   private int idade;
   private String[] cursos = new String[5];

   // [...]gets sets
 }
```

E tenho a classe Start:

```
public class Start {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

       AlunoPrivado aluno = new AlunoPrivado();
       aluno.setNome();
       aluno.setCursos("matemática");
    }
}
```

Comment: Não entendi bem o que quer. O `array` já está criado. Deseja criar os métodos que adiciona e remove os cursos que o aluno pode fazer, um por um? O que você chama de editar?

Comment: Me ajuda? *--* o vetor é para incluir remover listar e editar o curso para o aluno. Entende? Editar seria como editar um curso que está em uma posição...só para testar mesmo.

Comment: Vê se estou no caminho certo para fazer as outras partes. Sempre que possível coloque todo o código que tem que seja necessário. Isto ajuda a entender o problema melhor e desta forma eu poderia testar e dar uma versão funcionando.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Lembre-se que como tudo está privado, a classe que herdará isso não terá acesso a estes membros. Talvez queira mudar para `protected`.

Vai adicionar isso na classe `Aluno`:

```
private int totalCursos = 0;
public void addCurso(String curso) {
    if (totalCursos == 5) {
        throw Exception("Quantidade de cursos chegou ao limite");
    }
    cursos[totalCursos] = curso;
    totalCursos++;
}
```

Se quiser adicionar vários:

```
public void addCursos(String ... listaCursos) {
    if (totalCursos > 5 - cursos.Length) {
        throw Exception("Quantidade de cursos chegou ao limite");
    }
    for(String curso : listaCursos){
        cursos[totalCursos ] = curso;
        totalCursos++;
    }
}
```

Claro que dá para fazer de um jeito diferente. Mas essa é a ideia. Se fosse mais que um exercício, outros cuidados provavelmente precisariam ser tomados. Se pudesse fazer de outra forma fora do requisito especificado, daria para fazer melhor. Lançar `Exception` não é o correto em código normal, mas criar uma exceção nova só para isto em um exercício simples é exagero. Eu até faria sem exceção, mas esta não é a cultura do Java. Assim:

```
public Boolean addCurso(String curso) {
    if (totalCursos == 5) {
        return false;
    }
    cursos[totalCursos] = curso;
    totalCursos++;
    return true;
}
```

Note que preferi usar um nome começando com `add` para refletir que está adicionando. Se preferir, mude para `adiciona`.

Para listar:

```
public void listCursos() {
    for(String curso : cursos) {
        System.out.println(curso);
    }
}
```

Modificar:

```
public boolean changeCurso(String cursoModificar, String cursoNovo) {
    for(String curso : cursos) {
        if (curso.equals(cursoModificar)) {
            curso = cursoNovo;
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Outra versão direto pela posição do curso no cadastro:

```
public boolean changeCurso(int cursoModificar, String cursoNovo) {
    if (cursoModificar < 0 || cursoModificar > totalCursos - 1) {
        return false;
    }
    cursos[cursoModificar] = cursoNovo;
    return true;
}
```

Remover:

```
public boolean removeUltimoCurso() {
    if (totalCursos == 0) {
        return false;
    }
    cursos[totalCursos - 1] = null;
    totalCursos--;
    return true;
}

public boolean removeTodosCursos() {
    cursos = new String[5];
    return true;
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Array/InsertDataFull.java).

Dá para fazer a remoção pela posição e por busca, igual ao que foi feito na modificação, mas aí precisa estabelecer um critério de limpeza do *array*, o que apesar de ser relativamente simples, não é tão trivial para quem está começando.

Comment: resetar o array seria dificil?

Comment: Está feito. A não ser que esteja falando de outra coisa.

Answer (score 5):

Você pode usar esse método, que adiciona os nomes dos cursos ao vetor `cursos`, substituindo os valores anteriores, se havia algum:

```
public void setCursos(String ... novosCursos){
    int i = 0;
    for(String curso : novosCursos){
        cursos[i] = curso;
        i++;
    }
}
```

Para usar você só precisa separar cada parâmetro do tipo `String` do outro por vírgula:

```
aluno.setCursos("matemática", "português", "inglês");
```

Comment: Obrigada! Entendi.