# Sobre inserção de nomes em um vetor. O usuário coloca o nome do curso como argumento no método

Tags: java, array

**Tenho esse método:**

```
public void inserirCurso(String nome){
    System.out.println(" Cadastre seus cursos aqui.");
    for(int totalCursos = 0; totalCursos < cursos.length; totalCursos++){
        cursos[totalCursos] = nome;
    }
}
```

**Estou chamando o método assim:**

```
aluno.inserirCurso("matematica");
aluno.inserirCurso("historia");
aluno.inserirCurso("ciencias");
aluno.inserirCurso("informática");
aluno.inserirCurso("português");
aluno.listarCurso();
```

**Está imprimindo assim:**

> ```
> Cadastre seus cursos aqui.
> Cadastre seus cursos aqui.
> Cadastre seus cursos aqui.
> Cadastre seus cursos aqui.
> Cadastre seus cursos aqui.
> português
> português
> português
> português
> português
> ```

Achei estranho por que a mensagem "Cadastre o seu curso aqui." Está fora do for. O que fiz de errado como posso consertar isso?

**O listar**

```
public void listarCurso(){
     for(String curso : cursos){
         System.out.println(curso);
     }
}
```

**Agora está sendo impresso assim depois do totalCursos++:**

```
português
null
português
null
português
```

Comment: Não entendi qual é a dúvida, estava pronto para usar. A solução que o DarkHyudrA deu, é só voltar fazer o que eu tinha mostrado em http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/108701/101

Comment: @bigown realmente, agora também fiquei na dúvida. Eu não tinha visto aquela pergunta até então.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O seu `inserirCurso()` é que exibe na tela `Cadastre seus cursos aqui` várias vezes, já que você está chamando várias vezes o método.

Seu método inserção também não está correto, usar

`for(int totalCursos = 0;...cursos[totalCursos] = nome;`

significa que sempre vai sobrescrever todos os itens do vetor a partir da posição 0 do array até o último, guardando somente a última inserção. Por isso que imprimiu `português` repetidas vezes.

**Solução**

Se não for pra usar nenhum tipo de objeto como ArrayList, o mais básico que tu poderia fazer é:

```
public void inserirCurso(String nome){
    //System.out.println(" Cadastre seus cursos aqui.");
    cursos[totalCursos] = nome;
    totalCursos++;

}
```

Mas por favor note que um código desse não faz nenhum tratamento pra evitar que o índice esteja fora do tamanho do vetor.

Comment: Ele vai sobrescrever o vetor todo, e não somente a posição 0. Não é mesmo?

Comment: Se o vetor já tivesse algum conteúdo sim. Outra coisa é que não se sabe o tamanho dele, mas imaginando que ele imprimiu português 5 vezes, ele provavelmente criou o vetor já com 5 posições. Vou dar um pequeno edit.

Answer (score 4):

As suas 5 primeiras linhas que contém `Cadastre seus cursos aqui.` estão sendo impressas pelas 5 chamadas do método `aluno.inserirCurso()`. Daí, dentro desse método você preenche uma variável com o valor passado no argumento, o problema é que cada vez que você chama esse método você apaga tudo que já tinha sido escrito nela até o momento e preenche com o novo valor. Sendo assim, ela apenas manterá o valor do último valor passado como argumento que no caso do seu exemplo é `português`.

Você não nos mostrou seu método `aluno.listarCurso();`, mas provavelmente ele é só um for que percorre o vetor `cursos`. Sendo assim ele imprime todo o conteúdo dele, por 5 vezes consecutivas, que é o argumento da última chamada do método, ou seja: `português`.

Para consertar isso, depende um pouco do que você quer fazer exatamente, mas você provavelmente deseja alguma estrutura parecida com um ArrayList ao invés do vetor `cursos`, onde seu método de inserir cursos ficaria simples assim:

```
public void inserirCurso(String nome){
    cursos.add(nome);
}
```

Eu não sei onde você declarou ele, mas ficaria assim:

```
List<String> cursos = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Enquanto seu método de listar os cursos provavelmente não sofrerá grandes modificações.

Comment: Hummm interessante, mas com listas fica muito fácil ainda preciso entender melhor esse vetor. Eis a questão...

Comment: @AlineGonzaga o arraylist é só uma sugestão, o importante é você entender pq o erro aconteceu e pensar na melhor maneira para você evita-lo. Se precisar de ajuda em como vai ficar sua estrutura daqui para frente pode dar mais detalhes de como quer que ela fique. A sugestão de código do DarkHyudrA parece estar mais próxima do que você deseja, dá uma olhada nela.

Answer (score 3):

Acho que sua abordagem do uso de vetores não está correta neste código. Você deve verificar se o indice não está ocupado antes de inserir um novo curso, do jeito que tá, como o @Math e o @DarkHyudrA falaram, vai cadastrar somente o ultimo.

A partir do seu método `inserirCurso()`, você pode verificar se o indice está preenchido antes de atribuir um valor a ele. Quando você instancia um vetor, ele é criado com todos os indices como `null`, então você pode fazer a verificação seguinte:

```
public void inserirCurso(String nome) {
    System.out.println(" Cadastre seus cursos aqui.");
    for(int totalCursos = 0; totalCursos < cursos.length;totalCursos++) {
        if(cursos[totalCursos] == null) {
            cursos[totalCursos] = nome;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Desta forma, só será preenchido um indice que ainda não tenha sido atribuido uma string. Veja funcionando no **[ideone](https://ideone.com/KHe8Fj)**.

Note que foi possivel verificar um indice vazio como `null` por se tratar de um vetor de String, o método acima não funcionaria com tipos primitivos.