# Uma pessoa pode ter vários telefones. Como fazer isso com vetor e não com lista?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos

Não estou conseguindo associar `Telefone` com a classe `Pessoa`, uma pessoa pode ter até três telefones. Como é que faz isso?

```
package model;

public class Pessoa {

private String nome;
private String endereco;
private String sobrenome;
private Telefone tels[];


public Telefone[] getTels() {
    return tels;
}

public void setTels(Telefone[] tels) {
    this.tels = tels;
}

public String getNome() {
    return nome;
}
public void setNome(String nome) {
    this.nome = nome;
}
public String getEndereco() {
    return endereco;
}
public void setEndereco(String endereco) {
    this.endereco = endereco;
}
public String getSobrenome() {
    return sobrenome;
}
public void setSobrenome(String sobrenome) {
    this.sobrenome = sobrenome;
}

}
```

Classe Telefone:

```
package model;

public class Telefone {

private String telefone;

public String getTelefone() {
    return telefone;
}
public void setTelefone(String telefone) {
    this.telefone = telefone;
}
}
```

classe teste:

```
package model;

public class Teste {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Pessoa pessoa = new Pessoa();           

    pessoa.setNome("Aline");
    pessoa.setSobrenome("Gonzaga");
    pessoa.setEndereco("Bairro Barra");
    String telefones[] = new String[3];
    telefones[0] = "7627-86476";
    telefones[1] = "5362-56423";
    telefones[2] = "33333-3333";

    System.out.println(pessoa.getNome());
    System.out.println(pessoa.getSobrenome());
    System.out.println(pessoa.getEndereco());
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        System.out.println();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Inicie o construtor de `Pessoa` com `this.tels = new Telefone[3]`. Assim, só será possivel adicionar 3 telefones. Caso tente adicionar mais, será estourado um `IndexOfBoundException` que é a tentativa de acessar ou adicionar um indice inválido num array pre definido.

Comment: Fiz isso no construtor de Pessoa, coloquei o tels = new Telefone[3]. Mas na classe main eu criei um vetor do tipo Telefone com mais 4 elementos e rodou...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tem jeitos melhores de montar as classes, mas sem querer mexer na estrutura e respondendo diretamente a pergunta, eu faria assim:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Pessoa pessoa = new Pessoa();           
    pessoa.setNome("Aline");
    pessoa.setSobrenome("Gonzaga");
    pessoa.setEndereco("Bairro Barra");
    Telefone telefones[] = new Telefone[3];
    Telefone telefoneTemp = new Telefone();
    telefoneTemp.setTelefone("7627-86476");
    telefones[0] = telefoneTemp;
    telefoneTemp = new Telefone();
    telefoneTemp.setTelefone("5362-56423");
    telefones[1] = telefoneTemp;
    telefoneTemp = new Telefone();
    telefoneTemp.setTelefone("33333-3333");
    telefones[2] = telefoneTemp;
    pessoa.setTels(telefones);
    System.out.println(pessoa.getNome());
    System.out.println(pessoa.getSobrenome());
    System.out.println(pessoa.getEndereco());
    for (Telefone telefone : pessoa.getTels()) System.out.println(telefone.getTelefone());
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/OJfcDO). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/zbrxccka-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Class/Aggregation2.java).

Se a classe `Telefone` tivesse um construtor, seria mais fácil. Se a classe `Pessoa` tivesse um método melhor para adicionar os telefones, seria mais fácil ainda. O que já foi mostrado em respostas anteriores, por isso eu não vou reproduzir o que [já foi ensinado antes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/108701/101), que era bem melhor que este código.

Para o código ficar em ordem tem várias coisas que precisariam ser adicionados a ele.

Comment: Não entendi porque vc deu new depois de inserir no vetor o telefone.

Comment: Pra criar uma nova instância, cada elemento terá um NOVO telefone.

Comment: Espera só mais uma coisa, eu estou adicionado um novo valor no vetor ainda não entendi porque preciso de uma nova instância para criar um novo telefone...Por que que acontece isso?

Comment: Se ler o que você escreveu, já está respondido: "eu estou adicionado um novo valor no vetor". Como vai adicionar um novo valor sem ter um novo valor? Um novo valor é obtido criando uma nova instância. Está criando um novo telefone e colocando esse telefone no vetor. Eu até acho essa classe um exagero, mas já que criou ela, tem que ficar criando instâncias para ela.

Comment: Entendi! Obrigada...não havia pensado nisso antes...

Answer (score 3):

Bom, fiz uns ajustes no seu código, porém tentei minimizar o impacto, justamente para facilitar o seu entendimento das alterações e o porquê de ter feito elas.

Segue o código ajustado:

Classe Pessoa

```
public class Pessoa {

private String nome;
private String endereco;
private String sobrenome;
private Telefone[] tels;

public Telefone[] getTels() {
    return tels;
}

public void setTels(Telefone[] tels) {
    this.tels = tels;
}

public String getNome() {
    return nome;
}

public void setNome(String nome) {
    this.nome = nome;
}

public String getEndereco() {
    return endereco;
}

public void setEndereco(String endereco) {
    this.endereco = endereco;
}

public String getSobrenome() {
    return sobrenome;
}

public void setSobrenome(String sobrenome) {
    this.sobrenome = sobrenome;
}

}
```

Classe Telefone

```
public class Telefone {

private String telefone;

public Telefone(String t) {
    this.telefone = t;
}

public String getTelefone() {
    return telefone;
}

public void setTelefone(String telefone) {
    this.telefone = telefone;
}
}
```

Classe Teste

```
public class Teste {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Pessoa pessoa = new Pessoa();

    pessoa.setNome("Aline");
    pessoa.setSobrenome("Gonzaga");
    pessoa.setEndereco("Bairro Barra");
    Telefone[] telefones = new Telefone[3];

    telefones[0] = new Telefone("7627-86476");
    telefones[1] = new Telefone("5362-56423");
    telefones[2] = new Telefone("33333-3333");
    pessoa.setTels(telefones);

    System.out.println(pessoa.getNome());
    System.out.println(pessoa.getSobrenome());
    System.out.println(pessoa.getEndereco());
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        System.out.println(pessoa.getTels()[i].getTelefone());
    }
}
}
```

O problema do seu código original é que você não estava fazendo o `set` dos telefones no seu objeto `Pessoa`, além do que você não estava criando instâncias da classe `Telefone`, que é o esperado pela `Pessoa`.

Agora tente entender os ajustes que foram feitos e compare com o código original.

[]'s

Comment: Me explique isso por favor: System.out.println(pessoa.getTels()[i].getTelefone());

Comment: Você precisa indicar de qual posição está recuperando o valor a ser exibido. Claro que isso poderia ser feito de formas mais elegantes, mas como dito no corpo da resposta, não foquei nesse quesito.